# Minecraft on 18.04: Stop fullscreen minimize on focus lost

Tags: 18.04, gnome, minecraft, fullscreen

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with the Gnome desktop installed, and I have two monitors. Minecraft has... issues with running in Windowed mode on my system ([MC-144107](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-144107) for one), and is generally a smoother experience to run in fullscreen. The only downside is that Minecraft (and other fullscreen apps) minimize when focus is lost, for instance when switching to another app such as a browser on another monitor. That would be fine, except for gnome-shell bug [1749779](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1749779) which makes it a gamble each time I switch out of a fullscreen app as to whether or not my PC will freeze.

I've tried using `export SDL_VIDEO_MINIMIZE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS=0`, but it has no effect. Is there anything else I can do to stop Minecraft from minimizing in fullscreen when focus is lost?

Answer (score 0):

Set "Options... → Video Settings... → Fullscreen: OFF". Then use your window manager to fullscreen the game. For example in GNOME 3 I can hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>